# How to plot simple plot from DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Hellow I have DataFrame like below:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"target1" : [10, 0, 15, 10], "target2" : [50, 0, 20, 0], "ID" : ["1", "2", "3", "4"]})
```

And I need to create plot (bar or pie) which will show how % of ID have target1, how many target2, how many other (neither target1 nor target2).

I need results something like below:
T1 75% because 3 from 4 IDs have target1

T2 50% because 2 from 4 IDs have target2

other 25% because 1 from 4 do not have neither target1 nor target2

And I need have percentage description of columns and legend some if possible

[image]

Comment: i like your drawing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"target1": [10, 0, 15, 10], "target2": [50, 0, 20, 0], "ID": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]})
all = len(df["ID"])
value = [0, 0, 0]
for i in range(0, all):
    b = False
    if df["target1"][i] != 0:
        value[0] += 1
        b = True
    if df["target2"][i] != 0:
        value[1] += 1
        b = True
    if not b:
        value[2] += 1

# or you can use this
# value = [float(len([col for col in df["target1"] if col > 0])) / all * 100,
#            float(len([col for col in df["target2"] if col > 0])) / all * 100]
value = [(float(col) / all * 100) for col in value]
num_list = value
plt.bar(range(len(num_list)), num_list,
        tick_label=["target1 " + str(value[0]) + "%",
                    "target2 " + str(value[1]) + "%",
                    "default " + str(value[2]) + "%"])
plt.show()
```

[image: effect]

Answer (score 1):

- [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) as `'ID'` as we do not want to calculate on that column
- Check number of items not equal to `0` ([`df.ne(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html))
- get [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html)tiply by `100` to convert to percentage.
- create bar [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), use `rot=1`, otherwise `xticks` would be vertical.

To annotate the bars:

- save the plot object, loop through the `patches`
- `get_height` (the percentage values), and format it into appropriate label, by adding `'%'` sign
- `get_x` position and `get_height`, scale them by a factor marginally greater than 1, so that the labels do not intersect the bars.

```
>>> ax = df.set_index('ID').ne(0).mean().mul(100).plot(kind='bar', rot=1)
>>> for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()) + ' %', (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))
>>> ax.figure
```

Output:

[image]